# 'document' vs. 'content.document'

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a Firefox extension that adds elements to the loaded page. So far, I get the root element of the document via

```
var domBody = content.document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").item(0);
```

and create the new elements via

```
var newDiv = content.document.createElement("div");
```

and everything worked quite well, actually. But the problems came when I added a button with on onclick attribute. While the button is correctly displayed, I get an error. I already asked asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066191/javascript-onclick-onsubmit-for-dynamically-created-button), and the answer with document.createElement() (without content) works.

But if I remove the 'content.' everywhere, the real trouble starts. Firstly, domBody is null/undefined, no matter how I try to access it, e.g. document.body (And actually I add all elements _after_the document is fully loaded. At least I think so). And secondly, all other elements look differently. It's seem the style information, e.g., element.style.width="300px" are no longer considered.

In short, with 'content.document' everything *looks* good, but the button.onclick throws an error. with only 'document' the button works, but the elements are no longer correctly displayed. Does anybody see a solution for that.

Comment: There is a more easy way to access body. document.body

Comment: I tried 'document.body' but it is undefined, although the page is - at least should be - fully loaded

Comment: What is the error that is thrown when you click the button?

Comment: @Greg: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`. You can use array notation, but `.item()` is fine too.

Comment: See the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066191/javascript-onclick-onsubmit-for-dynamically-created-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine if you use [`addEventListener` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (at least this is what I used). I read somewhere (I will search for it) that you cannot attach event listener via properties when creating elements in chrome code.

You still should use `content.document.createElement` though:

```
 Page = function(...) {
   ...
 };

 Page.prototype = {
   ...
   addButton : function() {
     var b = content.document.createElement('button');
     b.addEventListener('click', function() { 
         alert('OnClick'); 
     }, false);
   },
   ...
 };
```

I would store a reference to `content.document` somewhere btw.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks a lot for that! --- I noticed when I click the button - of course the alert appears - the page reloads. Why is that so and how can I avoid that?

Comment: @Christian: Good question. I'm not sure. A `button` is by default a form submit button, but you have no form. Nevertheless, try to set the value of the `type` attribute to `button`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: Felix, you saved my day...at least you saved me a lot of time :). Many thanks again to you and all the others!

Comment: @Christian: So setting the `type` worked? In any case, you're welcome and happy coding! :)

Comment: Yes, `button.type="button"` did it! Thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer doesn't have a real explanation and there are too many comments already, so I'll add another answer. When you access the content document then you are not accessing it directly - for security reasons you access it through [a wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) that exposes only actual DOM methods/properties and hides anything that the page's JavaScript might have added. This has the side-effect that properties like `onclick` won't work (this is actually the first point in the list of [limitations of XPCNativeWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Limitations_of_XPCNativeWrapper)). You should use `addEventListener` instead. This has the additional advantage that more than one event listener can coexist, e.g. the web page won't remove your event listener by setting `onclick` itself.

Side-note: your script executes in the browser window, so `document` is the XUL document containing the browser's user interface. There is no `<body>` element because XUL documents don't have one. And adding a button won't affect the page in the selected tab, only mess up the browser's user interface. The global variable `content` refers to the `window` object of the currently selected tab so that's your entry point if you want to work with it.

Comment: Thanks, Wladimir, for explaining! I only found bits and pieces referring to the various differences. I always like _why_ my solution does actually work, or why not :).