# generating HTML elements with the click of a button

Tags: html, button, onclick

```
<input type="button" value="Scramble" onClick="scramble();">
<p id="scramble">
</p>
```

The button that I have right now will generate a scramble but I would like it to also create two buttons. One that reveals the solution and the other that reveals a hint.

Comment: You might want to visit [How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Please check other stacks first next time.
[Javascript: onclick/onsubmit for dynamically created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066191/javascript-onclick-onsubmit-for-dynamically-created-button)

Code

```html
 <button onclick="isPressed()"> Press here</button>
<script> 
function isPressed(){
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'hint';
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  
    button.onclick = function(){
    alert('I am a hint!');return false;
  };
  
  var button2 = document.createElement('button');
    button2.innerHTML = 'solution!';
  document.body.appendChild(button2);
    button2.onclick = function(){
    alert('I am a sulution');return false;
  };
};
</script>
```